# Inappropriate Google Custom Search results by location

Tags: java, google-api, google-custom-search

I'm working on a Java application which can return the same results to a regular Google search using the Google Custom Search API.

I know there are many factors such as cookies, location, language, etc. But a rough approximation would be really good!

I've found the [parameters](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/customsearch/v1/java/latest/) I can use by the API.

However, setting the **'gl'** (Geolocation) to **"us"** and **'hl'** (Interface Language) parameter to **"en"** (United States), I still get results in another language from the country where I live.

I can set the **'lr'** value to **"lang_en"**, but a regular Google search user wouldn't use search filters for a simple search.

The core of my code looks like this:

```
public static List<QueryResult> getCustomResult(String term, int resultNumber) throws IOException {

Customsearch.Cse.List actQuery;
List<QueryResult> items = new LinkedList<>();

//Number of loops. Each loop gives back 10 results.
int loops = (int) Math.ceil((resultNumber) / 10.0);

for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
  actQuery = CustomSearchInstance.getCs().cse().list(term)
      .setCx("ENGINE_ID/CX")
      .setNum(10L)
      .setStart(1L + (long) i * 10)
      .setGl("us")
      .setHl("us");

      // Language restriction
      //.setLr("lang_US")

  Search results = actQuery.execute();

    for (Result result : results.getItems()) {
      QueryResult queryResult = new QueryResult(result);
      items.add(queryResult);
    }
}
return items;
}
```

I've also read, that I can set the user IP, during building my CustomSearch instance:

```
Customsearch cs = 
  new Customsearch.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null)
    .setApplicationName("APP_NAME")
    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new CustomsearchRequestInitializer("API_KEY","USER_IP"))
    .build();
```

I've tried many IPs, but it didn't change the results list.

Can you guys suggest me any ideas how to get real location based results?

Comment: I am using the custom search api and it seems to be impossible to get the same results as the web search.

Comment: I can totally understand that, but it's a bit weird why do I get different location results, since I've explicitly set these values.